# about SQLCODE -104 (error) during select in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-zos

I have been trying to adapt a working "INSERT"  into a SELECT statement and keep finding a error -104

a)Can someone please help me understand  the reason why the "." on   "where" clause (below) works when I run  with an  "insert"   but gives me an error when  using on a "select" clause? 
b)How should the "INSERT" criteria be written correctly when using a SELECT?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance on this question

Insert:

```
 INSERT INTO  SISPD2.SIS_DAILY_RECALC                            
         (CIN_NUM,PGM_DIV_FG,NON_CA_FG,PGM_EXCPT_FG,WTW_FG)   
 (SELECT C.CIN_NUM, C.PGM_DIV_FG, C.NON_CA_FG, C.PGM_EXCPT_FG,
         C.WTW_FG                                             
    FROM  SISPD2.SIS_INDV C                                  
   WHERE C.CIN_NUM NOT IN (SELECT CIN_NUM FROM  SISPD2.SIS_DAILY_RECALC)
```

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Select :

```
    SELECT C.CIN_NUM  ||','||                                          
         C.PGM_DIV_FG ||','||                                        
         C.NON_CA_FG  ||','||                                        
         C.PGM_EXCPT_FG ||','||                                     
         C.WTW_FG   ||','||                                        
  WHERE (C.CIN_NUM NOT IN (SELECT A.CIN_NUM                        
                            FROM  SISPD2.SIS_DAILY_RECALC A));
```

DSNT408I SQLCODE = -104, ERROR:  ILLEGAL SYMBOL ".". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT
         BE LEGAL ARE: , FROM INTO
DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 42601 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE

Comment: Be careful when tagging. You should only tag the DBMS relevant to your problem.

Comment: Not familiar with db2, and having a hard time figuring out exactly what you are asking, but I just came across the (rarely supported) `||` concatenation operator the other day; it looks to me like your second query is trying to concatenate the WHERE onto the single result field, which could confuse the query parser.

Comment: You're missing the `FROM` clause -- you must `SELECT` `FROM` something.

Comment: thank you so much mustaccio :)

Comment: thank you so much Uueerdo :)

Comment: Sean, sorry, I will be more careful

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be concatenating a statement together unless you're building a dynamic statement you intend to `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`

```
 SELECT C.CIN_NUM  
         , C.PGM_DIV_FG
         , C.NON_CA_FG
         , C.PGM_EXCPT_FG
         , C.WTW_FG
  WHERE (C.CIN_NUM NOT IN (SELECT A.CIN_NUM
                            FROM  SISPD2.SIS_DAILY_RECALC A));
```

Comment: thank you so much Charles , yes, I was trying to build a dynamic statement

Comment: I appreciated everyone's valuable comments -  thanks to all my  problem was solved :)